# Why the footer is not sticked to bottom?

Tags: css

I noticed the glitch that i can't remove somehow, on all pages of the website the grey footer is not sticked to the bottom of the screen...

Here is the small page:

As i can see the white space under footer belongs to `<body>` tag but i can't fix this.

I tried:

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
```

But in did not help, also as changing padding, margin styles of body, content or footer.

Help please.

Comment: Your HTML is not semantic, that is why. You are creating your footer like `<div class="footer"></div>` instead of `<footer></footer>`. Why?

Comment: I changed it locally and it did not help. Any constructive ideas??

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan - `<footer>` is only valid in html5, not everyone is using that you know.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Does it even matter? Before html5 everyone did it like this, and noone had problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I'm finding has to do with the `line-height` property set on your `body` tag. Removing that property seems to fix the issue.

I would recommend using line-height only where necessary (ex. If you need to use it on your nav or in your content tag, do it).

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Setting `position: absolute` will work if its parent container is `position: relative`.

I got it to work like so:

```
.b-footer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and you want to add `position: relative` to your `.b-content` container so the absolute works. I see it working in Chrome right now.

Comment: You can see that it is not a solution, just scroll down and white space is there. (Google Chrome testing)

Comment: Off of the top of my head, the solution that should fix instances for pages that aren't vertically tall enough is having `position: fixed;` with `bottom: 0;` on your footer element

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a button there.

Find the following line:

```
    <button id="authorize-button" style="visibility: hidden">Authorize</button>
```

and remove it, or do something about it. Perhaps move it up

Comment: Without having to remove it, the OP can simply use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`

Comment: It should and in my Chrome it does... What do you mean "fully"?